# Grails validate runtime error

Tags: validation, grails, runtime-error

I use grails validate() function in my very simple update action inside a controller. The problem is very starnge. `validate`() is not executed at all and giving no error and stopping the execution. I am using Grails 2.3.3

Only the log gives the following error:

```
Runtime error executing action
```

Here is my controller code:

```
def update() { 

        println(params);

        def study = Study.findByUid(params.uid);
        study.description = params.description;

        println(study); //study is found and printed  
        study.validate();
        println("here"); //not executed and code below is also not executed

        if(study.hasErrors()){
            study.errors.each{
                println it
            }
            render 'not saved!'
        }

        if (!study.save()) {

            println("Error");
            withFormat renderInternalError
        }
        else {

            render "OK"
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
Request received for '/study/update':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1eaba95c

servletPath:/study/update
pathInfo:null

Security filter chain: [
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  MutableLogoutFilter
  RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter
  GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2013-11-27 11:56:04,738 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG filter.GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter  - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@f6816ea3: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@b29dace9: Username: creator@example.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: A1813ED8541AAC773CEF349475DB24A2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2013-11-27 11:56:04,738 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: '{0}'
2013-11-27 11:56:04,740 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] TRACE intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition  - new candidate for '{0}': '{1}':{2}
2013-11-27 11:56:04,740 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] TRACE intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition  - config for '{0}' is '{1}':{2}
2013-11-27 11:56:04,741 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] TRACE core.StandardWrapper  -   Returning non-STM instance
2013-11-27 11:56:04,743 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter  - No cacheable annotation found for POST:/hdspro/grails/study/update.dispatch [controller=study, action=update]
2013-11-27 11:56:05,651 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController@98f1784]: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [update] of controller [com.digithurst.hdspro.StudyController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
2013-11-27 11:56:05,651 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Resolving to view '/error' for exception of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException], based on exception mapping [java.lang.Exception]
2013-11-27 11:56:05,651 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exposing Exception as model attribute 'exception'
2013-11-27 11:56:05,951 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - StackOverflowError occurred when processing request: [POST] /hdspro/study/update - parameters:
acessionNumber: 3
uid: 3
description: Elbogen123
Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [update] of controller [com.digithurst.hdspro.StudyController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:102)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:69)

......
```

/

```
Study class:
class Study extends Document {

    String uid
    String description
    String accessionNumber
    Date date

    String toString(){
        return "Study" + uid + ": " + description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace

Comment: and please post your constraints

Comment: Can you post the `Study` class? thanks.

Comment: Do I need any includes or anything?

Comment: Please, post the code of your domain class and your UrlMappings. Did you changed the 500 mapping?

Comment: The code of my domain class is above? What is the 500 mapping?

Comment: There is a StackOverflow error shown above:
 StackOverflowError occurred when processing request:

Comment: @Jacob post your `UrlMappings.groovy`

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I've read, you say you did not add any constraints to the domain class. From what I know `validate()` uses these constraints to check if your instance has errors. Ex:

```
class CartType {
    String name
    static constraints = {
         name blank: false, nullable:false, maxSize: 50 
    }

    String toString(){name}
}
```

In this example class we have a cartType. When we call `validate()` grails will check the constraint block. In this case it will check that the name is not left blank in the form, it cannot be null and that it's max size is 50 characters.

**Note:** The constraints block can also help grails build the database.

If you did not declare any contraints `validate()` will not have anything to check against. You will also most likely get an error when a value is null, because, by default, nullable is set to false.